# Именование классов в БЭМ

Tags: css, классы, бэм, именование

Вопрос по правильному именованию классов в БЭМ.

Собственно есть шапка, и 2 элемента внутри - это логотип и поле поиска с кнопкой.

Вот структура:

```
<header class="page-header">
    <div class="page-header__line"></div>
    <div class="page-header__wrap">
        <div class="page-header__logo">
            <img src="img/header-logo.png" width="161" height="38" alt="whitesquare">
        </div>
        <div class="page-header__search">
            <input class="page-header__search-input" type="text" placeholder="Search">
            <button class="page-header__search-btn">GO</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

В данном случае интересует блок с поиском. Я не планирую использовать поиск где-либо еще на странице, поэтому делать его блоком не вижу смысла. Правильна ли разметка?

А если мне нужно было бы сделать его отдельным блоком? Тогда так?

```
<div class="page-header__search">
    <div class="search">
        <input class="search__input" type="text" placeholder="Search">
        <button class="search__btn">GO</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Заранее спасибо.